# Spark scheduling / architecture confusion

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm attempting to setup a Spark cluster, using the standalone / internal Spark cluster (not Yarn or Mesos). I'm trying to understand how things need to be architected.

Here's my understanding:

- One node needs to be setup as the Master
- One or more nodes need to be setup as Workers
- The application I write (in Java) will be passed the ip:port of the Master to create the spark context
- When I run any code on in the java app, on the spark context, e.g a filter/collect, that code will automatically be run across the worker nodes.

My questions are:

- Do I need to setup a separate server/node for running the driver, or can/should it be run from the master/one of the worker nodes?
- If I wanted my filter/collect code to run at regular intervals, do i need to take care of the scheduling myself from within the driver?
- Edit: It looks like the recommended way of submitting jobs is thru a bash script? That seems like a manual process. How does this get handled in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can run your application from non-worker node - it's called client mode. If you run your application inside some worker node, it's called cluster mode. Both of them are possible.
2. Please take a look at Spark Streaming, it seems that it will fits your requirements. You can specify that every one hour data will be collected and computation will start. You can also create cron task that will be executing `spark-submit`.
3. Yes, recommended way if throught `spark-submit` script. You can however run this script from cron jobs, from Marathon, Oozie. It very depends on what you want to do.

If you want more info please write more about your use case, I'll try to update my answer with more precise information

Update after comment: I recommend looking at [Spark Streaming](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html) - it has connector to Kafka and you can write aggregations or custom processing, via foreachRDD, to data received from specific topics.
Pseudocode of algorithm:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
val directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[
     [key class], [value class], [key decoder class], [value decoder class] ](
     streamingContext, [map of Kafka parameters], [set of topics to consume])
val topicFirst = directKafkaStream.filter (_._1 == "topic1")
val topic2 = directKafkaStream.filter (_._1 == "topic2")

topicFirst.foreachRDD (rdd => {
    // do some processing with data collected from specified time window
});
```

About cron, you can ivoke `nohup` with `spark-submit`. However it's better to have one long-running jobs than many small if you must execute them in small time intervals. However it seems Spark Streaming will be good for you, them you'll have one long running job. Mandatory Word Count example is [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/DirectKafkaWordCount.scala) :)

Comment: I need to monitor a few kafka topics. Each topic will need a different job to handle it. E.g topic a will get handled by job a, topic b by job b, and so on. All jobs need to share the same master / worker nodes.

Any ideas how to architect this? Thanks.

Comment: If a job is run thru cron, etc, is it expected that it will run once and exit, or is it expected to stay in memory and repeat itself when it needs to?

Comment: @ClickUpvote I've added an update - please look at Spark Streaming, it seems that it will fits your requirements. You will have one long running job that will be triggered by Spark at specified time intervals

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Last question: In the example above, does the code inside the `foreach` get run repeatedly for each new item that's received from kafka? Likewise in the wordcount example you linked, it calls `awaitTermination` which implies that it will stay in memory, but where's the code for polling kafka and processing the new / incoming messages? From the code, it looks like it'll only be run once

Comment: It will be executed every 2 seconds - above you've got configuration of Streaming Context. You can also set one interval in context and then specify window operation with different window, which must be multiplication of base interval. `awaitTermination` means that driver will not quit just after start, but stay up and wait for next micro batch

Comment: What I'm confused about is, how will the streaming context know which code will be executed every 2 seconds?

Comment: @ClickUpvote Spark magic ;) In streaming context you provide info, that scanning should be done every 2 seconds. When you wrote some map, filter, foreachRDD, etc, you're creating DStream. This DStream holds information about time interval on which data should be processed. So Spark will count: second 1, second 2: check!, second 3, second 4: check! If DStream have window() specified with 4 seconds interval, then Spark will not execute this DStream in second 2, but in second 4. So it will be: second 1, second 2: check! no action on DStream, second 3, second 4: check! And action performed on DStr